# Saving a SavedModel: ValueError: At least two variables have the same name

Tags: tensorflow

I have a function that saves a SavedModel.

During training, this function is called from time to time, every N epochs, to replace the current SavedModel with a newer one.

```py
def save_savedmodel(sess, snapshot_dir):
    example = tf.get_collection("example")[0]
    label = tf.get_collection("label")[0]
    softmax = tf.get_collection("softmax")[0]
    logits = tf.get_collection("logits")[0]

    savedmodel_dir = snapshot_dir + "/saved_model"

    shutil.rmtree(savedmodel_dir, ignore_errors=True)
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(
        sess,
        savedmodel_dir,
        inputs={"example": example},
        outputs={"softmax": softmax, "logits": logits},
    )
```

The script used to work, until I upgraded tensorflow to 1.12.

Now, the first time this function is called, it works, and subsequent calls result in the attached stacktrace, complaining that there are two variables named `batch_normalization/beta/Adagrad`:

```
ValueError: At least two variables have the same name:batch_normalization/beta/Adagrad
```

The first confusion is that this isn't true. This is what I see when I dump all of my variables just before `calling simple_save()`

```
for name in [n.name for n in tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().node]:
    print(name)
```

```
batch_normalization/beta/Adagrad/Initializer/Const
batch_normalization/beta/Adagrad
batch_normalization/beta/Adagrad/Assign
batch_normalization/beta/Adagrad/read
batch_normalization/beta/Adagrad/Initializer/Const_1
batch_normalization/beta/Adagrad_1
batch_normalization/beta/Adagrad/Assign_1
batch_normalization/beta/Adagrad/read_1
```

There is `batch_normalization/beta/Adagrad` and `batch_normalization/beta/Adagrad_1`: is this normal or is this fishy?

What is confusing to me is that  I am just *saving* the model. I am not *restoring* a model. So, is my graph already corrupted before I call this function a second time, or does saving a model modify the session in some way?

```
Pass your op to the equivalent parameter main_op instead.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/tictactoe/train.py", line 412, in <module>
    train(sess)
  File "src/tictactoe/train.py", line 312, in train
    write_snapshot(sess, saver, global_step_val, "champion")
  File "src/tictactoe/train.py", line 185, in write_snapshot
    save_savedmodel(sess, snapshot_dir)
  File "src/tictactoe/train.py", line 209, in save_savedmodel
    outputs={"softmax": softmax, "logits": logits},
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/simple_save.py", line 85, in simple_save
    clear_devices=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/builder_impl.py", line 415, in add_meta_graph_and_variables
    saver = self._maybe_create_saver(saver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/builder_impl.py", line 272, in _maybe_create_saver
    allow_empty=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1102, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1114, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1151, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 773, in _build_internal
    saveables = self._ValidateAndSliceInputs(names_to_saveables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 673, in _ValidateAndSliceInputs
    names_to_saveables = BaseSaverBuilder.OpListToDict(names_to_saveables)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 572, in OpListToDict
    name)
ValueError: At least two variables have the same name: batch_normalization/beta/Adagrad
```